# Emailing a Visualforce Chart

Tags: visualforce, email, charts

Does anyone know of a good way to send a Visualforce chart through email? I was hoping that I could put them in a dashboard and send them out on a scheduled refresh, but I got a warning message saying that the component cannot be displayed in email. Also the dependence on javascript rules out a lot of other possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this using Visualforce charts, you will need to look into using an external library that allows this (e.g. Google Charts)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate a PDF from VF page and send as an attachment. Please refer to this [link](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/apex/send-email-with-generated-pdf-as-attachment-from-trigger/) on how to do it. Hope this will help you.

Comment: That is one of the issues with the charts using javascript. When you render the page as a pdf, the chart component won't be drawn.

Comment: There is a way if you can use google chart API. You can get the data in VF page from controller and pass as URL parameters to Google chart API. [Example](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=200x100&chl=January|February|March|April). You will get an image which can be embeded in a PDF with <apex:image> tag. I have tested it and can able to add it in a pdf.

Comment: I had heard about the google chart api, but I was a bit hesitant to use it since I am in China and most things related to google are blocked (your link for example). However, since the salesforce asia/pacific servers are in Tokyo, I'm thinking that if I embed it in a pdf there, it might be okay.

Answer (score 0):

By using this visualforce component you can send a visualforce chart/dashboard through email.

```
<apex:component access="global">
<apex:image value="https://instance.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?[...]">
</apex:image>
</apex:component>
```

upload your image as document  and use that url in component.

or you can use Static Resources to send Chart/Dashboard, for that you have to remember following things:

1 make your static resource Public by nature.

2 Save your chart's URl in your Static resources.

3 The spelling of the Static Resource match exactly to the path inside the ZIP file.
Do let me know if this helps.

Comment: The chart I want to send is not currently an image. It is a Visualforce page that makes use of the <apex:chart> component. Is there a way that salesforce can draw the chart server-side and provide it as an image? 

Or is there a similar way to use an SOQL query and a bit APEX to generate a chart in salesforce that can be sent through email?

Answer (score 0):

First make a VisualForce page like this (it will be rendered as pdf):

```
<apex:page controller="MyPdfTemplateController" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf" >
<apex:image value="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=400x200&chl=January|February|March|April" width="400" height="200"/>        
</apex:page>
```

If chart image is not rendered then you need to allow access to google chart api. Go to Settings / Security Controls / Remote Site Settings and add `http://chart.apis.google.com` as new remote site.

This did the trick to me.

The apex:image code works also in VisualForce email templates.

More about google image chart api here: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/

Note that api is deprecated.